# Entity Framework The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have this classes:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Key { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { set; get; }
}

public class Hobby : Activity
    {
        public int SectionId { set; get; }
        public Section Section { set; get; }
    }

public class Location : Activity
    {
        public int StudioId { set; get; }
        public virtual Studio Studio{get;set;}
    }

public class Tag
    {
        public int Key { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public bool Valid { set; get; }

        public Tag()
        {
            this.Activities = new List<Activity>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { set; get; }
    }
```

Between the Tag and the Activity there is a many to many relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().
              HasMany(c => c.Tags).
              WithMany(p => p.Activities).
              Map(
               m =>
               {
                   m.MapLeftKey("ActivityId");
                   m.MapRightKey("TagId");
                   m.ToTable("Pointer");
               });
```

Now in my controller i'm trying to do this: For each tag to get all the activities pointed by him and for each activity to get: the studio(in case the activity is a location) / the section(in case the activity is a hobby). To do this i firs have to tell EF that it has to lazy-load some objects in relation with the tag. I tried to do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Tag> GetTags()
        {
            using (WelcomolidayDbContext db = new WelcomolidayDbContext())
            {
                return db.Tags
                    .Include("Activities")
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.Select(a => a.Creator))
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.Select(a => a.Pictures))
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.OfType<Hobby>().Select(a=>a.Section))
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.Select(a => a.Pictures))
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.OfType<Location>().Select(a => a.Studio))
                    .Include(t => t.Activities.Select(a => a.Tags)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

But i get the error:

```
   The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. 
Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for 
collection navigation properties.Parameter name: path
```

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong, or if there is a way around this?
Thanks.

Alexandru.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  Are you doing anything in your `Include` method besides those two things?

Comment: Sorry I don't udersand, a read the error message but i don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, that i know, but what is the source of the problem? The fact that I use a condition('OfType'<...>) or ... what?